# Laravel scope query wherePivot

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to better at using scopes to make cleaner calls to specific information.

Currently I have a `weeks`, `workouts` and `week_workout` tables. I am trying to get a workout for `Carbon->today()`. To do this I need to access the `date` field on the `week_workout` table.

week_workout

```
| week_id | workout_id | date
```

Workout.php

```
 public function weeks(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Week')
                    ->withPivot( ['program', 'warmup', 'date'] )
                    ->orderBy('date', 'asc');
        }

public function scopeToday($query)
        {
            return $query->with('weeks')->wherePivot('date', Carbon::today());
        }
```

Controller

```
$workouts = Workout::today()->get();

When I do this I get `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `workouts` where `pivot` = date)
```

I am not sure why its looking for pivot column. The docs seem to suggest it will look for date in the pivot table if I load it with the relationship but it appears I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have to use `whereHas`. I updated the scope to just take any date to make it more powerful:

```
public function scopeDate($query, $date)
        {
            return $query->whereHas('weeks', function ($q) use($date){ 
                $q->where('date', $date); 
            }); 
        }
```

then in the controller:

```
$workouts = Workout::date( Carbon::today() )->get();
```